# Dataset comparison with Null Value c#

Tags: c#, null, dataset, comparison

Goodday

I can't seem to use my dataset in a Null comparison
I'm trying to make an statement (attempts go below) where it will only continue my code when my dataset is empty.

Code 1:

```
if ((string)dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] != null)
```

^ just skips my if, I know  that it's empty (checked my watch), still continues even when it is null.

Code 2:

```
 long Recid = 0;
 Boolean checkrecid = long.TryParse((string)dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"], out Recid);
 if (checkrecid == false)
```

^ Crashes at my Tryparse. I know you can use Trycatching, but I don't want to use it, cause it will make my program run slower, and it needs to read a good 10000 lines a day ...

Error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Meaning that it can't find anything, but I know that already.

**EDIT:** ***I do not want an error. Any previous methods, who all work in other cases, return an indexoutofrange error. I'll add this ..
The dataset is filled with data from an SQL server based on phonenumbers and other data.
If he can't find the phonenumber, which comes from a text file, he will return nothing, no row, no column, nothing.***

Thanks in advance,
DZ

Comment: What is the string value of `(string)dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"]`, I am guessing it is not null which is why your original check didn't work, maybe its the empty string? So checking if `((string)dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] != "")` may work?

Comment: Could you try `if(!(dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] is DBNull))` instead?

Comment: For the first line, did you try comparing to `string.Empty` rather than `null`?

Comment: Rows {System.Data.DataRowCollection} System.Data.DataRowCollection Count 0 int <- empty

Comment: Two times no guys .. It still gives me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

> int strTables = dts.Tables[0].Rows.Count; 
>       if (strTables == 1){ //code goes here}

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `DBNull.Value` instead of null

EDIT: Index outside the bounds may mean there are no rows at all. Try replacing your if with this:

```
if (dts.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] != DBNull.Value)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, but do not cast to string for this comparison. `if (dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] != DBNull.Value)

Comment: Did you remove the cast to a string like Olivier mentioned? I forgot about that in my answer.

Comment: I did ... Added more info at the top

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if ((string)dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] != null)
```

needs to be

```
if ((string)dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] != DBNull.Value)
```

Or you could delete that check:

```
Boolean checkrecid = long.TryParse((dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] ?? string.Empty), out Recid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((string)dts.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RECID"] is DBNull)
{ // will go here }
```

Answer (score 0):

A type-safe alternative is using [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method.  It will return 'null' instead of DBNull.Value for empty fields.

```
if (dts.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("RECID") != null)
```